# PHP / Composer cannot redeclare

Tags: php, composer-php

I was happily working away in my development environment and suddenly I started getting the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare composerRequire7a368ac394ae1d2e857becf2a235ebaa() (previously declared in [APP_ROOT]/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:56) in [APP_ROOT]/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 59

I haven't made any changes to speak of in composer dependencies (although I think I did do a `composer update` somewhere in that timeframe but no changes to the dependencies/packages used so nothing big should have changed.

Notably, when I checkout the repo on my laptop I do NOT get this error but if I `git clone` a clean repo and then `composer install` on my main development machine I DO get this error. So I'm assuming it must have some machine-specific origin but I'm running out of ideas on what that might be.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> **Note**: I'm running PHP 5.3.28 on OSX; my app uses namespacing and is PSR0 compliant

---

Also of note is that I'm running PHPUnit 4.0.17 and the error is triggered at the very first stages of trying to run a unit test (it doesn't matter WHICH unit test). Here's the stack trace:

> ```
> 0.0009     636648   1. {main}() [APP_BASE]/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:0
> 0.0465    1423664   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() [APP_BASE]/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:54
> 0.0465    1424280   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() [APP_BASE]/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:132
> 0.0465    1424280   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() [APP_BASE]/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:141
> 0.0674    2123344   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleBootstrap() [APP_BASE]/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:638
> 0.0681    2139872   6. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() [APP_BASE]/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:808
> 0.0681    2140008   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() [APP_BASE]/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Fileloader.php:77
> 0.0774    2144176   8. include_once('[APP_BASE]/tests/test-loader.php') [APP_BASE]/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/Fileloader.php:93
> 0.0775    2146736   9. include('[APP_BASE]/vendor/autoload.php') [APP_BASE]/tests/test-loader.php:2
> ```

Comment: So what are the `autoload_real` lines 56 and 59?

Comment: It's just the composer's default autoload file ... I would think yours would be the same as mine but in case it's not ... line 56 is a function definition `function composerRequireb319f8584bff24b05e527f91a6f7f8bf($file)` and line 59 is the closing bracket for this function where the only line of the function is to require the passed in file.

Comment: put it on http://pastebin.com please then. And make sure you're looking on the correct file - I hardly doubt the closing bracket might cause such an issue.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/gNeVmHDu

Comment: For what it's worth a moved my code back to a commit that definitely was working and it gets this same error.

Comment: The file you pasted doesn't look like the file that may cause this error. Are you 200% sure it is that exact file?

Comment: I am 190% sure. I will include the full stack trace in my question though as maybe there's something in there that will help pinpoint it.

Comment: Check what code loads `autoload_real.php` file. It must be only run once, whereas your code runs it multiple times

Comment: The thing is ... it isn't my code ... at least that seems unlikely considering i've rebased to an earlier working version and it no longer works. I've even done a clean checkout of the repo and same result. :(

Comment: so check what code includes it multiple times.

Comment: And how do I do that? and what IS being included twice?

Comment: `include 'file.php'; include 'file.php';` <--- that's how I include a file twice

Comment: :) Yes I know how to include a file twice. I mean how do i determine which file is being loaded a second time in this case?

Comment: It's `autoload_real.php` that is included twice

Comment: but that's all done via composer ... no one would include that file themselves, right? I'll check ...

Comment: It doesn't matter what does that :-) You have an issue. If you want to solve it you must find what causes it

Comment: I have validated that that particular file is NOT included anywhere in my code (I never use includes just namespacing and "use" as my app is PSR0 compliant) but I also checked the `vendor` directory and there are no references to this file there either except of course Composer's own autoload.php (as you'd expect)

Comment: I have had a similar error before a few times. Doing a `composer dump-autoload` did the trick for me to fix it.

Answer (score 10):

Delete `composer.lock` and `vendor/` and run `composer update` again.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem when I made a copy of an existing project directory and tried to run phpunit on the new directory. Finally figured out that when I executed phpunit, it was running out of the old directory. I ran this:

> which phpunit

And saw that it was running from my composer vendor directory:

> /home/vagrant/Code/MYOLDPROJECT/api/vendor/bin/phpunit

I ran phpunit from the new directory and the problem disappeared:

> /home/vagrant/Code/mynewproject/api/vendor/bin/phpunit

Comment: glad you sort it out. for me the problem was different but enough time has passed I'm afraid I don't remember enough of the details.