# Cannot redeclare composerRequire... - Composer issue?

Tags: php, cakephp, osx-mavericks, composer-php, mamp

My development env is OS X Mavericks using MAMP and NetBeans.

I'm experimenting with a CakePHP plugin (CakeResque) and after installing via Composer, the following error is being logged:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare composerRequiref2c9cc1d84da6e308a0f610da161cf55() (previously > declared in .../app/Vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:47) in
>   .../app/Vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 50

Others are using this plugin and at this point, I don't think it is related to the plugin.  The developer of the plugin has been kind enough to help me troubleshoot it through a [github issue](https://github.com/kamisama/Cake-Resque/issues/70) but with no luck.  In my core config file, I have:

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/Vendor/autoload.php';
```

I'm not requiring Vendor/autoload anywhere else in my application.

I found this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234927/php-composer-cannot-redeclare) but it was never answered - this is the exact same issue I am having.

Because I am using MAMP, I have pointed my local php to the MAMP php bin - now when I run `which php` it is pointing to my MAMP directory.  This may have nothing to do with it but I'm trying to include everything.

Running `composer self-update` says everything is up to date.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're redeclaring the function twice (firstly on /autoload_real.php line 47). Check if you're including the file twice (use include_once() instead of include()).

Comment: Thanks Charlotte.  Yes, I have ensured I'm not purposely calling it twice from my code and yes, i am using require_once when loading it initially.  Thanks.